# In Julia, how to reject words with a certain character?

Tags: string, julia, list-comprehension

I want to collect words that do **not** contain a certain character.

I feel it should be much easier than  my current solution (which makes heavy-handed use of regular expressions).

But alas, I'm just not getting it.

Here's my current solution, that works:

```
want(s) = match(r"\?",s) == nothing
[s for s in lst if want(s)]
```

Everything else gives me syntax errors:

```
[s for s in lst if not '?' in s]
[s for s in lst if not ('?' in s)]
filter((x) ->  not ('?' in x),["?asdas","bbb"])
```

I can do it with a verbose ternary operator:

```
 filter((x) ->  ('?' in x ? false : true),["?asdas","bbb"])
```

but that does not seem elegant.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`not` is not a valid keyword. the negation operation in julia is `!`. for example, this code works:

```
[s for s in lst if !('?' in s)]
```

Comment: So simple. I knew there was a more elegant solution. Thnx.

Comment: `in` is fine here, but if you use `occursin` you can filter on more general substrings, even regexes.

Answer (score 1):

The follwing is a more concise variant using `filter`:

```
filter(x -> '?' ∉ x, ["?asdas","bbb"])
```

`∉` is basically just `!in`, and can be written as `\notin`.  Maybe more efficient (you'd have to test that for your actual data) is to use a regex and `match` as

```
filter(x -> isnothing(match(r"\?", x)), ["?asdas","bbb"])
```